# Bash script opening new gnome-terminal with sudo password as variable

Tags: bash, variables, sudo

I'm making a script to keep my system up to date. In the script I open a new gnome-terminal to have the code executed there as I do want the output, but not in my main terminal window. However, I can't seem to get the sudo password to work.. Here's my script:

```
echo "Please provide me with your SUDO password"
#make password variable for later use. 
read password 

echo "Updating your package information.."
gnome-terminal --quiet --wait -- echo "$password" | sudo -S apt-get update
echo "Command executed."

echo -e "Upgrading packages.."
#etc..
```

When I just echo the password in the 'new' terminal it does work, I can see the password (or any variable) just fine. However with the above the result is always sudo: no password was provided.

I am not looking to disable my sudo password and the executed command has to be in a new window.

Comment: I didn't test it, but it looks like this command: `| sudo -S apt-get update` is executed in the window that runs the script, not in the new terminal. Why not just do `gnome-terminal --quiet --wait -- sudo apt-get update` and put the password to the new terminal?

Comment: Also note that `echo "$password" | sudo -S apt-get update` is highly insecure, because you can see the password in process list and some malware could detect that and with sudo password... it can do anything to your computer.

Comment: @MichalH Would it matter if the script will be executed one single time, directly after a fresh install?

Comment: A bit less insecure, but still bad practice. This should be safe: `sudo -S apt-get update <<< "$password"`.

Comment: @MichalH That unforunately doesn't work as it still prompts me for my password in the new terminal window. The reason I do not want to put my password in is because my script will open multiple windows where some (around 10 windows) require a sudo password.

Comment: Again, the `<<<` redirection is happening in the window that runs the script, not in the new terminal. You need to pass it to gnome-terminal in a way that the current shell will not interpret it. Maybe this will work: `gnome-terminal --quiet --wait -- 'sudo -S apt-get update <<<'"$password"`. But here I think it's going to appear in the process list. In this case you better save the password to a temporary file with appropriate permissions and delete the file afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont use gnome, and it apparently does not have an official man page. The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) added by Debian or Ubuntu is not uptodate. It seems to suggest you need to provide the command as a single string with `-e`, and examples on askubuntu show it apparently working in 2010.

More recently, `-x` can be used, and it then takes the rest of the line, but since you have a pipe `|` in your command you might need to do instead:

```
... -x bash -c "printf '%s\n' '$password' | sudo -S apt-get update"
```

assuming `'` is not in your password. (`printf` is preferred to `echo` in case of special characters in the password).

You might prefer to pass the password in the environment instead:

```sh
PW="$password" gnome-terminal ... -x bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$PW" | sudo -S apt-get update'
```

As you commented, `-e` and `-x` are now deprecated, and the command should be passed after `--` as in:

```sh
PW="$password" gnome-terminal ... -- bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$PW" | sudo -S apt-get update'
```

Comment: Maybe better `-e 'printf %s '"$password"' | sudo ....'`, to stay out of trouble with quoting?

Comment: You are right that printf is preferable, and I've updated, but sadly it doesnt help with password containing a quote, as you still need to quote `$password`. It would be best to put the password in the env, then it would be a variable and not a string. I'm presuming the string is passed to `bash -c ...` or similar.

Comment: Using the env would help indeed. Maybe you can add this to your answer?

Comment: When using any of the above I get the following error: `There was an error creating the child process for this terminal` `Failed to execute child process “printf "%s\n" "$PW" | sudo -S apt-get update” (No such file or directory)` Any ideas?

Comment: Re-reading the man page, which provides no examples, perhaps it should be `-x` instead of `-e`. If that fails try `-x bash -c 'printf....'`. Sorry, I dont have acces to gnome at the moment.

Comment: I've got it to work with the `-x bash -c 'printf....'` solution. However, both `-x` and `-e` are deprecated and the new syntax is `--`. If you change your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer. There's one more question I have.. Why do we have to do `PW="$password"` before we start the command? I tried running the rest of the command with just `"$password"` directly instead of `"$PW"` but that doesn't seem to work properly. I also tried to move the `PW="$password"` to another line (as I will need it more often and would rather only declare it once) but that also doesn't work.

Comment: When you set a shell variable on the same line as a command like `A=1 bash -c 'echo $A'` then A is set in the environment of that command only. When `A=1` is on a line of its own, A is set in the env of the current shell only. If you say `export A=1` on its own line, then A is set in the env of the current shell and in all new processes, so that may be what you wanted. The use of `$password` works in the first example because it is in a string in double-quotes, so gets expanded immediately. The later examples use single-quotes so no variables get expanded until the command is parsed by bash -c